# chrome extension callback fires too early

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm using chrome.tabs.executeScript callback for working asynchronously and orderly step by step. unfortunately the callback fires too early:

```
chrome.tabs.update(tab.id, {
        url: "https://www.example1.com"
    }, function(){

            chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {
                code: 'var userData = ' + JSON.stringify(userData) + ';'
            }, function() {
                chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {file: "test1.js"}, function(){
                    setTimeout(function(){
                        chrome.tabs.update(tab.id, {
                            url: "https://www.example2.com"
                        },function(){
                            chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {file: 'jquery.js'}, function(){
                                chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {file: "test2.js"},
                                        function(res){console.log(res);});
                            })
                        })
                    }, 4000)
                });
            });
    });
```

test2.js and it's callback is running even when we are still in the first website ("https://www.example2.com"). and it raises errors.

Comment: I remember there's already filed issue on crbug.com

Comment: Any new information on this?